# Mercurial - Update versioned project from external repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Me and my team want to start work on a website based on an open-source framework. For this I want to get the latest source code and start with this as our baseline.

My question is, how should we approach update scenarios, meaning how should I merge changes from the project's repository into mine? My only idea would be to create patches and apply them locally, should this be enough?

Thank you

Comment: Is the framework also tracked in Mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see a problem here. You could just setup to use 2 repositories - one is your local repository and one is remote project's repository. For pushing you use only your local repository. Whenever there are changes in the projects repository, you update from it (giving you for example 2 branches - with your current changes and with remote repository changes), merge and push to your local.

Using patches is also an idea, though it would give you 2 branches anyway and less flexibility.

Comment: Can I set up more than 1 repository in the same folder?

Comment: You don't setup multiple repositories, you specify multiple remote repositories - one is your local repository(like for your company) and one is remote repository (like project's repository on github or somewhere else). It's done on Synchronization page in TortoiseHG or you should manually edit your config file. Remote repositories are used for pushing/pulling data.

Comment: Well, my team has made a transition year ago. We're still learning things :) You're welcome.:)